# Function guaranteed to be called in C++ during abrupt termination or exit

Tags: c++, exception

What function in C++ is guaranteed to be called during abrupt termination or exit which can perform the clean up activity ..

Comment: technically nothing is *guaranteed* -- if you don't have a UPS and the power goes out, or your processor's power supply fails, or the clock oscillator fails (all of which are infrequent but possible events) then the CPU will stop working.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what you mean by "abrupt termination" there are several different options:

- Global destructors will be called upon *normal* termination (return from `main`, or call to `exit()`).
- [`atexit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) registers a function to be called on normal termination.
- [`std::set_terminate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/) registers a function that will be called when an exception is thrown but not caught, or when "exception handling has to be terminated for some other reason".
- [`sigaction()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) registers functions to be called when your program receives *signals*, many of which will normally abruptly terminate your program.  Signal handlers may be called when the program is in an internally-inconsistent state, and therefore are *extremely* limited in what they can do.  For instance, they cannot do anything that might allocate memory.  Also, this API is not available on Windows; there are equivalents but I am not familiar with them.

Note that all operating systems in common use provide at least one way to abruptly terminate your program that *cannot* be intercepted from your code.  For instance, Unix has signal 9 (`SIGKILL`) which you can't register a handler for.  *This is a feature, not a bug.*  You, the user, need a way to make a process go away even if it has done everything in its power to make itself indestructible.  Furthermore, no code can protect your process when the user's pet rabbit gnaws through the power cord on the computer.  Because of this, it might be a better use of your time to design your program to *recover from crashes* cleanly, rather than trying to clean up when a crash happens.  See this article on "[crash-only design](http://lwn.net/Articles/191059/)" for more about that.

Answer (score 2):

Read about `atexit` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/). However it will not be called in **all** cases (for example, calling `abort` will not trigger the function you registered with `atexit`).

You can implement your own signal handler, then all the signals will pass there and you can do whatever for each of them.

Comment: This is as close to what the OP asked for as one can get. There is no guarantee that the exit handlers will be called. The program can trigger a signal that cannot be caught or isn't being caught; the programmer can call `abort()` to force the program to exit abnormally or `_Exit()` to force the program to exit normally but to bypass the exit handlers. However, a return from main or a call to `exit()` will run the exit handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `set_terminate()`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/

There are other similar function in the same header, that are usable for complementary scenarios.

Comment: This is causing the abrupt termination, not being called by it.

Comment: @David One of us can't read. He is asking how to handle program exits caused by exceptions.

Comment: @Let - where? The word exception doesn't even appear in the question. He's asking for a way to be called on **any** type of termination - abrupt of regular exit. At least that's what I read from the question.

Comment: @littleadv It is tagged exception-handling.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        // all your code here
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // cleanup
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently not, since the docs for set_terminate state that "A terminate handler function is a function automatically called when the exception handling process has to be abandoned for some reason."

Comment: This doesn't cover everything, but it's still a good baseline.

Answer (score 0):

What environment you're working in? by abrupt do you mean Ctrl+C or kill -9 signal?
On unix/linux you can mask some signals and provide handlers, but as far as I am aware, you cannot mask all signal (9 is an example of a signal that can't be masked, and it'll kill your process abruptly)

Some even lower level overriding on OS operation could be available, but I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert and I just know some few things about C++,  but I know you can create handles in Unix and C in order to detect a concrete signal and then, execute a function and later, terminate the program by "exit(n)" for example.

You can do it using [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) or [sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction), but the problem is that you only can use this method for any signal except SIGKILL or SIGSTOP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function that captures all scenarios and works on all platfroms. If you need something for Windows you will have to handle SEH(Structured exception handling) as well. You will have to define and set handlers for various scenarios(SEH, C++ Exceptions, SIGABRT, Terminate etc.) that execute common cleanup code and. Check zack's response here for handling SIGABRT signals.

For SEH you can add a SE converter to handle SE excpetions and convert them to C++ exceptions, look at [_set_se_translator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5.aspx) for more information about how to handle SEH exceptions.

You can refer to [this documentation for set_terminate handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6fk7h29.aspx) and [this is a good reference for set_unexpected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h46t5b69.aspx).

You will have to write your own handler that will be called for every scenario.

In the end I would reccomend using some existing libraries for this purpose, I like [crashrprt](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/crash_report.aspx).

Comment: I am working on Windows .. Purpose of the question is certain clean up activity I want to put in such a way that no matter why & from where program exit (graceful or crash ) It should do it ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with signal handling?  I would recommend that you study that first and then come back with questions regarding it.  It looks like a couple people have already alluded to it, but here is a good resource to check:

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Signal-Handling.html

Writing your own signal handlers will allow you to determine what you want to do when a particular signal is caught.  As stated, there are some that can't be overridden, and for good reason.  You don't want to let someone override kill -9 simply because a program that's impossible to kill could be created.  However, a straight kill signal or something such as ctrl-c, ctrl-d, etc, can be caught and handled in the way of your choosing.